# Where and when were the earliest bronzes made which intentionally added tin to copper?

Tags: bronze-age, metallurgy

I’m trying to update my understanding of the early timeline of bronze use in Eurasia.  Much of my knowledge on the subject came from the 1976 edition of Tylecote’s *History of Metallurgy*, which is now very out of date in many critical ways.  For instance, the Balkan bronze artefacts from the fifth millennium BC were unknown then.  (I’ve recently read Radivojević’s 2013 paper ‘[Tainted ores and the rise of tin bronzes in Eurasia, *c*6500 years ago](https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/1420706/)’ on these discoveries.)

Tylecote says:

> The earliest bronzes seem to be those from Mesopotamia, i.e. the early City States which depended upon the deposits of the Anatolian and Persian highlands for copper, and probably trade for their supply of tin.  When one examines the chronology of the sites in the Euphrates–Tigris delta region, one is impressed by the agreement in dating for the appearance of true tin bronzes.  The first appearance of bronze in all the sites seems to be between 3000–2500 BC; before then, the metals were pure or arsenical coppers.
>
> The Royal graves at Ur date to the 1st Dynasty of about 2800 BC, and we find true tin bronzes with 8–10%Sn.  An axehead had a typical cored cast structure with the delta phase, and contained blow holes.

He is distinguishing these ‘true tin bronzes’ from earlier ‘low-tin bronzes’ which he speculates (elsewhere) could have resulted from tin impurities present in the copper ore.  He implies these Sumerian bronzes are the earliest bronzes made by intentionally adding tin, probably smelted from cassiterite, to copper.  My question is: is this still the consensus view?

The Balkan discoveries don’t change this, as Radivojević says they seem to have been made by smelting stannite, a tin-copper mineral, rather than combining tin and copper from separate sources.

The closest I've got to an answer is in a 2010 paper by Kauffman, ‘[Metallurgy and Ecological Change in the Ancient Near East](https://www.academia.edu/1989221/Metallurgy_and_Ecological_Change_in_the_Ancient_Near_East_Backdirt_2011)’, which says:

> The Sumerians of the EDIII period (ca. 2500 BCE) were the first to adopt tin bronze technology…  As discussed above, tin bronze technology was invented in the mountainous areas to the north of Mesopotamia some half-millennium earlier, but the technology and tin resources were never in demand until the time of the Sumerians.

Although not a peer-reviewed paper, it has been cited by multiple peer-reviewed papers and the author seems to be a respected academic in the field.  However Kauffman puts the earliest Sumerian bronzes three centuries and two dynasties later than Tylecote (which may simply be a revised date), and I'm struggling to follow what the ‘the mountainous areas to the north of Mesopotamia’ are: Iran or Anatolia?  Kauffman quotes a [2002 paper by Palmieri *et al*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/44158005_Chemical_Composition_and_Lead_Isotopy_of_Metal_Objects_from_the_Royal_Tomb_and_Other_Related_Finds_at_Arslantepe_Eastern_Anatolia/link/568a4c1308ae1e63f1fbb8a9/download) for the Anatolian artefacts near Arslantepe (Melid), and that explicitly says ‘Tin bronze objects were not among the retrieved artefacts’.  Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: Define how to measure "*intent*"?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens – Good question.  If there's evidence that the bronze was produced by combining tin or tin ore with a low-tin copper or copper ore, I think I'm happy to assume intent unless there's a good reason not to.  It may have happened rarely by accident, and perhaps that is how bronze was discovered (though I'm inclined to think a deliberate attempt to get the strength of copper with the colour of tin is more likely), but I can't see such accidents being remotely common, so likelihood of the resultant artefacts having survived seem vanishingly low.

Comment: I'm still unclear how you will identify "*evidence that the bronze was produced by combining tin or tin ore with a low-tin copper or copper ore*" all these thousands of years later, in a finished product.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Several strategies have been used.  If the percentage tin in the artefact is much higher than in any known local copper ores, it's a strong indication that tin was added.  That's the easiest approach.  Another is when you find evidence of tin or tin ores being imported in bronze-producing regions.  Finally you can look at the ratios of impurities (or isotopes of them) and if they match known low-tin copper deposits or tin ores, that's a good indication that two metals were combined.  Analysis of slag can also sometimes eliminate the possibly of stannite smelting.

Comment: Thank you; and good work. Please add these points to the question, as comments are ephemeral, and subject to deletion at any time.